# Does a inherited class inherit a nested class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, nested

I  have an template class, for example

```
template<class T,class Key>
   class BinaryTree:{
   public:
   class node {};
   }
```

and now I want to inherit from the class, for example:

```
class AVLTree : public Binary Tree
```

The problem I get stuck with is that the functions I want to implement in AVLTree don't recognize the node. For example let the function be

```
void rotateLL(node* n)
```

The compiler says:

```
node has not been declared
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry, first time I am asking here. I edited the question.

Comment: You are missing very important details. Is `AVLTree` also a template class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node` is what's called a dependent name, since it's a member of the base class which depends on template parameters.  You need:

```
template <class T, class Key>
class AVLTree : public BinaryTree<T, Key> {
public:
    void rotateLL(typename AVLTree::node *n);
};
```

Comment: You are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what you're running into--your code in the question has quite a few typos, so it's impossible to guess what the code you're really working with might look like.

Nonetheless, the basic idea of what you're apparently trying to accomplish can work fine. For example, the following compiles without a problem:

```
template<class T, class Key>
class BinaryTree {
public:
    class Node {};
};

template <class T, class Key>
class AVLTree : public BinaryTree<T, Key> {
public:
    void rotateLL(typename BinaryTree<T, Key>::Node *n);
    // or: void rotateLL(typename AVLTree::Node *n);
};
```

Comment: @aschepler: Oops--quite right. (Serves me right for trusting VC++).